# How hiera works?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have the following hiera data files (yml).

- hiera/data/domain/abcd.com
- hiera/data/role/webserver.yml

lets say i have a puppet node which has 'webserver' role assigned and its hostname is abcd.com

Now under - hiera/data/domain/abcd.com file, i have this

```
config::xyz_category::name: 'bbbb'
```

and i have the following data under - hiera/data/role/webserver.yml

```
config::xyz_category:
  username: 'aaaa'
```

my hiera data lookup order is like below (hiera.yml)

```
:backends: yaml
:logger: console
:merge_behavior: deeper
:yaml:
  :datadir: /etc/puppet/branches/hiera/data
:hierarchy:
   - fqdn/%{::fqdn}
   - role/%{::rolename}
   - domain/%{::domain}
   - defaults
```

So my question is lets say i have a module written for this 'webserver' role.

Inside that module, can i call hiera data like below?

```
$config = hiera('config::xyz_category', {})
```

so that

```
$config['name'] should return 'bbbb'
$config['username'] should return 'aaaa'
```

Comment: Have you tried to do that?

Comment: This is a pretty good hierarchy and role setup you have going by the way. A lot of casual Puppet developers seem seem confused about best practices, but this is rather good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not exactly.

An Hiera priority lookup, such as performed by the `hiera()` function, looks up a *complete* value associated with the key, taking the whole value from highest-priority hierarchy level that provides one.  In the case you describe, that value will be a hash with exactly one key, 'username'.

On the other hand, if you want to assemble a hash value from multiple levels of the data hierarchy, then you're looking for a [hash-merge](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/latest/lookup_types.html#hash-merge) lookup.  Hiera supports that, but you need to use the correct lookup function:

```
$config = hiera_hash('config::xyz_category', {})
```

Note in particular that the difference between `hiera()` and `hiera_hash()` (and `hiera_array()`) is primarily about *lookup strategy*, not about the type of the return value.  The plain `hiera()` function can return scalars, hashes, and arrays, as appropriate.

Comment: He could also change `config::xyz_category` into a hash with `name` and `username` keys. All of this reminds me of how I cannot wait until Puppet Data Provider goes production ready.